# Trying to fill out an online form using selenium but it can't find the element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am new to selenium and have tried searching for this element using xpath, ID, and class, however I cannot seem to find it. Upon using inspect element, the element is certainly there.

```
<input type="email" class="chakra-input rr-auth-web-user-email-input css-1wpvo2" placeholder="Email" name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress" required="" aria-required="true">
```

I have tried

```
login = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='emailAddress']"))).click()
```

Adjusting for ID, class name, etc, but the code can't seem to find it.

I am expecting the code to find the element and clicking on it, I have done this before on other sites however I cannot seem to figure out why it is not working here.

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

```
<input type="email" class="chakra-input rr-auth-web-user-email-input css-1wpvo2" placeholder="Email" name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress" required="" aria-required="true">
```

To click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#emailAddress[name='emailAddress']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='emailAddress' and @name='emailAddress']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you're defining an event as a variable (the `click()` event, assigned to the `login` variable).
You need to assign the actual element to the variable, as:

```
login = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='emailAddress']")))
```

And now you should be able to click on it:

```
login.click()
```

Also, this click should happen without assigning the element to a variable, by simply doing:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='emailAddress']"))).click()
```

Selenium documentation can be found [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/).